# Copying File - System Argument Exception, Invalid Characters in Path

Tags: c#

After putting a picture in the database, I want to copy and rename the picture to another folder but I always get this error - Invalid characters in path even though the path is correct. I already copied and paste the path from my directory to avoid errors. Initially, this code belongs to the add image part of my program(and it is working). But when I tried to copy paste this code to update image part it's no longer working, I really don't know why.

```
//choosing a picture and putting the path to pathID.Text
OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
dlg.Filter = "All Files(*.*)|*.*|JPG Files(*.jpg)|.jpg|PNG Files(*.png)|*.png";
dlg.Title = "Select Employee Picture.";
if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string picLoc = dlg.FileName.ToString();
    pathID.Text = picLoc;
    pictureBox5.ImageLocation = picLoc;
    this.pictureBox5.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
}
if (pathID.Text == "")
{
    MessageBox.Show("You didn't add your ID Picture");
}
else
{
    try
    {
        //converting image to binary
        byte[] imageID = null;
        FileStream fstream = new FileStream(this.pathID.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fstream);
        imageID = br.ReadBytes((int)fstream.Length);
        fstream.Close();                    

        //storing image to database
        string login = "server=localhost;database=id;uid=root;password=root;";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(login);
        conn.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE picture SET `Picture_Employee`=@EMP where Employee_ID=@ID";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMP", imageID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", sampleID.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close

        //copying file from one path to another
        string newp = "C:\\Users\\Owner\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\ID\\ID\\bin\\Debug\\formattedpic\\" + sampleID.Text + "-" + label1.Text + "-IDPIC.jpg";          
        if (File.Exists(newp))
        {
            int i = 1;
            while (File.Exists(newp))
            {
                newp = "C:\\Users\\Owner\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\ID\\ID\\bin\\Debug\\formattedpic\\" + sampleID.Text + "-" + label1.Text + "-IDPIC"+i.ToString()+".jpg";
                i++;
            }
        }

        //tried to show path in message box - it is showing correctly
        MessageBox.Show(newp);
        System.IO.File.Copy(pathID.Text, newp);
        MessageBox.Show("ID PICTURE Updated");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show us an example for the path? (newp)

Comment: C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ID\ID\bin\Debug\formattedpic\0000002-JOHN-ACCESS-IDPIC.jpg

Comment: That looks ok. What about pathID.Text?

Comment: C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ID\ID\bin\Debug\pic\elmo.jpg (i'm still testing images first). Initially, this code belongs to the add image part of my program(and it is working). But when I tried to copy paste this code to update image part it's no longer working, I really don't know why.

Comment: In else part you are using `this.pathID.Text` but this would be blank and second `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", sampleID.Text);`; sampleID.Text would be again blank. Could you please check whether do you have proper values in both the fields before any operation on them?

Comment: @AmneshGoel That else part belongs to the second `if` statement, so he would already have a value in `pathID.Text` by then.

Comment: Since I'm just testing if the code works, I put a default values to sampleID.Text (0000002). For pathID, the path will be inputted in the textbox once you browse for a picture.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Uri.IsWellFormedOriginalString` to check your paths.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformedoriginalstring.aspx

By the way, these will let you know what's not allowed (on top of the Internet resources):

```
var invalidPathChars = Path.GetInvalidPathChars();
var invalidFileChars = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars();
```

Comment: Since I'm just testing if the code works, I put a default value to sampleID.Text which is 0000002.

Comment: C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ID\ID\bin\Debug\pic\elmo.jpg - OLD PATH

C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ID\ID\bin\Debug\formattedpic\0000002-JOHN-ACCESS-IDPIC.jpg - I want it to be like this

Comment: @George I'm curious to see what the values of `pathID.Text` and `newp` are when you try to copy the file towards the end: `System.IO.File.Copy(pathID.Text, newp);`  There has to be something off with one of them.

Comment: @George For your `if else` statement, could you try `if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pathID.Text)) {...}`  If your `pathID.Text` is `null` (since I don't know how your constructor looks it's safe it assume this) then your `if` statement will not be true.

Comment: Try one thing.. instead of path of C:\\\\\\ use D:\\\ and see the result.

Comment: @George Could you output `pathID.Text` before you copy the file.  Check to make sure that it matches.  I know you've checked `newp`, but you should check the source file path as well.

Comment: Also I tried showing both path ID.text and newp in messagebox to see if the paths are correct, and they are correct.

Comment: @George Hmm.  Can you run `Uri.IsWellFormedOriginalString` method on both of them? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformedoriginalstring.aspx)

Comment: its returning false for both paths, i don't know whats wrong

Comment: @George Hmm, so they're not properly formatted.  I'd have to guess that one of the variables in your destination path is either `null` or contains an invalid character.  What I would do is get the array of invalid characters using `Path.GetInvalidPathChars()` and check if your strings contain any of those characters (String.Contains()).

Comment: So even if I just copy paste the code(which is working from my other form), I can still have those invalid characters?

Comment: @B.K. when it's telling me to remove the backslashes of my path

Comment: @George I'm not sure, but I have a strong belief that there's a `\0`  in one of your paths.  You won't see it in `Debug.WriteLine()` or `MessageBox.Show()` because it appears as an empty character.  It's not one of the characters you can have in your name.  I'd debug and step through your code, making sure that all of the variables along the way are valid.

Comment: @B.K. what do you mean by \0? How come I cannot see it? I also tried to retype everything but it isn't working.

Comment: @George `\0` is `null`.  You can't see it because it doesn't exist visually.  It's the null terminator character.  If you have a null string, that's most likely what you'll see -- nothing.  But you're not allowed to have it as part of your path, because, in reality, it still exists.  Null terminator is at the end of character arrays, such as strings.  x86 example would look like this: `myPath db "path",0`